# Angular2 replace text by components

Tags: angular

I'm displaying a text string in my component template.

```
<p>{{ text }}</p>
```

Now if I wanted to replace the word "candy" by "apple" in this text automatically, that would be easy with for example a pipe:

```
<p>{{ text | replaceCandy }}</p>
```

However, trouble begins when I want to replace "candy" by a hyperlink (HTML). The HTML only work if used like this:

```
<p [innerHTML]="(text | replaceCandy)"></p>
```

This is already kind of an issue, because the text variable might be insecure. So this isn't really the best option.

It gets more complicated still if I wanted to replace "candy" by a custom component I made: AppleComponent. Replacing the string "candy" by "" doesn't work. The output is empty.

Extra info: I'm using a pipe because it's easy to reuse. Not really a necessity though. Just looking for the best solution to the problem.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Should the text value be input to a custom component?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the text value to be input to a custom component, you can declare an input value on the custom component using syntax like this

```
export class CustomComponent {
    @Input() inputText: string;
```

Then you use the component in the original HTML, and databind the value using attribute syntax:

```
<p><custom-component [inputText]="text"></custom-component></p>
```

Comment: I want the word "candy" in the text string to be automatically converted to a specific component.

The text is dynamic and will always be different. It is based on user input.

For example "I want candy" should be transformed to "I want <apple></apple>".

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [`ngSwitch` statement](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgSwitch-directive.html) to choose between different components:

```html
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="text" />
<span [ngSwitch]="text">
  <apple *ngSwitchCase="'apple'"></apple>
  <orange *ngSwitchCase="'orange'"></orange>
  <div *ngSwitchDefault>found no match</div>
</span>
```

When `text` is `apple` then the `apple` component will be shown. When the `text` is `orange` the `orange` component will be shown.

Comment: That is if text is equal to "apple". But the text variable can be for example: "I have an apple and Klas also has an apple. The result would be "I have an <apple></apple> and Klas also has an <apple></apple>."